# Does AL.exe work with X.509 Certificates

Tags: .net, x509, sn.exe, al.exe

I would like to delaySign and later fully sign .NET assemblies with X.509 Certificates.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delay signing is for strong names, not for code signing with certificates.

- Strong names are used to identify
  versions of assemblies and to provide
  a unique name.
- Code signing allows for the
  identification of the code publisher,
  ensures the file was not modified
  since signing and can be revoked.

So two different things and they're independent of each other. Authenticode signing must be done *after* the code has been strong named signed, as signing an assembly with a strong name changes the assembly.